# Why does Angular give me this error, when I have needed modules?

Tags: angular, module, uuid

When I try to use command ng it gives me this error.

```
Unknown error: Error: Package exports for '\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\uuid' do not define a valid '.' target
```

I have tried to uninstall and install angular, update node modules everything, but nothing seems to solve this problem

Comment: What is your NodeJS version?

Comment: You can also try npm i -g  uuid@latest

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nodejs version `v13` had known issues with this. Tried with `v12.16.3` and it's working. Either use latest `v14.5.0` or official LTS `v12.16.3`.

FYI:
Check node version with `node -v` on command prompt/ terminal